# Vibration and Brake Issues in Bajaj Dominar 400 UG motorcycle

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, vibration, abs, bajaj

I have a Bajaj Dominar UG-2019 motorcycle which I have riden for around 6000 Kms. I have been noticing that it vibrates a lot **between ~3000 and ~5000 RPM** and vibration reaches to footpegs and handlebar. During this I can hear a buzzing noise too from the front part of the bike. Beyond the aforementioned RPM range there is no visible vibration. The vibration is more in lower gears(1,2,3).
The other problem is with brakes(disc, dual channel abs). The rear brake bite is as low as nonexistent and the front one too lacks the bite. The front brake also seems stiff at times while applying. I had a discussion with service center technician about this but he told me that low bite was due to the ABS but this braking issue creates huge problem while riding at high speed on highways where I struggle to stop while applying sudden brakes.
What might be the possible reason and solution for the above problems(vibration, braking).
Any suggestion or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any servicing or checks on brakes etc?

Comment: The motorcycle has been serviced thrice(chain cleaning,  filter change,  engine oil change etc) as part of scheduled services but nothing specific was done for the brakes by the service center.